# Swift: Getting a string width to make a frame (using CGRect) in swift 2.2

Tags: swift, string, ios9

How can I get width of a string in swift 2.2 and iOS 9 ?
What I want to do is to create a UIButton programmatically but its frame needs to fit the title size which will be inferred at runtime.
Note: We know frame's height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have set the text of button just call :-

`yourButton.sizeToFit()`

Comment: This is what I exactly looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size by declaring your button title text as `NSString`. Try this:

```
let title: NSString = "some title"
let size = title.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)]) //you can add NSForegroundColorAttributeName as well
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `NSString` method [boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:).

e.g.:

```
let rectNeeded = aString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: aFont!], context: nil)
```

Note that you need to cast you String into an NSString before being able to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use frames. Use auto layout. If you use auto layout to place this button into the interface, it will be sized to fit its text *automatically*.